# How to make asp.net web app published under isv Folder in CRM Working in OFFLINE mode?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I  have published a asp.net web app in ISV folder in CRM. and i am accessing this web app in IFrame. its working fine in online mode , but when i goes to offline mode it gives me error  Server Error in '/' Application HTTP Error 404 - Not Found Version Information: Cassini Web Server 4.0.0.0 '. I wanna know how to make this web app working in offline mode?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show your code and please give more information about the version of Dynamics CRM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't provisioned your web-application to the client. When the client is online, it shows only the pages which are deployed to the ISV directory.

In order to get them working offline, you have to manually deploy them to each clients local ISV directory. There is no automatic deployment.